# groupby msql query

Tags: php, sql, mysql, group-by

I have a bunch of ID's.
I can assign them once a day.

I need to query my database, see if they're any ID's available to hand out (if I didn't hand out all of them in a 24 hour period), and if there's any available, write a new row to the database saying that the ID has been handed out. I also need to know which user held which ID at a certain time.

The only way I can figure this is by creating two tables - one `active_ids` (contains who owns a particular ID right **now**) and one `id_records` (contains who owned IDs currently and in the past).
Then I would say something like:

```
UPDATE active_ids SET user_id=xyz WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(current_timestamp) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) > 84600 LIMIT 1;
```

and then pusing another record to `id_records` with the data.

Is there a way I can do this with one table?
I'm using PHP and MySQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, provided the user id's aren't the actual primary key, you could just timestamp all the user_id creations and then search using time-based queries to see what is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a "day" column of type `DATE` and a "user_id" column, and use a composite primary key of `(day,user_id)`.

Or what I suspect might be a better idea: have a genuinely unique id, then have call the non-unique id an "access code" instead and have a composite unique constraint.